# progressBar in XNA game

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Does anyone knows how to add a timer to control the speed of a progress bar? 
in addition that I need that time to use it in another function that its only running while the progress bar movement and stops when the progress bar stopped .. so in specific my need is  set a timer to control the progress bar and how to get it ?

and by the way.. my coding in c# using XNA game developement in visual studio

Regards,

Comment: Alright, what have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I believe DaPhunk means what techniques have you attempted. Have you made a `ProgressBar` class, if so, can we see a code excerpt? Is there any other code we can see that would help us help you? (in reply to deleted OP comment)

Answer (score 1):

There is no timer function per-say in XNA, but you can latch onto the number of seconds that have gone by.

The `Update` and `Draw` methods in `Game` provide a `GameTime` object, which holds the `TotalTimeElapsed` property. Keep a copy (just make sure its a copy and not a reference) of that object as a previous time and compare it with the "current time". If the difference is over a target value, do your event.

```
//at top of class
private TimeSpan previousTime;
private TimeSpan targetTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); //5 seconds
private bool isFirstUpdate = true;


//later down in your update
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(isFirstUpdate)
    {
        previousTime = new TimeSpan(gameTime.TotalElapsedTime.Ticks);
        isFirstUpdate = false;
    }

    if(gameTime.TotalElapsedTime - previousTime >= targetTime)
    {
        //do some event, and don't forget to re-set previous time
        previousTime = new TimeSpan(gameTime.TotalElapsedTime.Ticks);
    }
}
```

Comment: `GameTime.Elapsed...`'s type is `TimeSpan`

Comment: Exactly. You need to find a way to replace a timer control that would be normaly found in WinForms. `ElapsedGameTime` is a `TimeSpan`, so set a "target time" to the "tick interval" you would normally set in a timer control.

Comment: @gunr2171 yes exactly this is what i want. from where i get that tick interval ??

Comment: See my edit. It is a simple method to use a "timer" in the beginning of your update function.